# Is there a way to run current script in a split window (mimicing VSCode for example)?

Tags: terminal, external-command

When editing a script in vim, I can run it with `:! bash %` or `:! python %` for python scripts. When running the script, vim kinda goes back to the terminal, runs there, and then, after "ENTER" it goes back to the Vim window.

I would like to have it open a small window, that I can jump to and from, for execution. Something like:

1. split window (let's say 1/3 height)
2. run the script there

Is it possible? (splitting the window is easy, but running the script in said window - not that easy)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what the `:terminal` command is for:

```
:terminal bash %
:terminal python %
```

Comment: Wow. Simpler than I thought. Thx! I think I'm going to map this to something like CTRL+e[xecute] and CTRL+SHIFT+e[xecute]

Answer (score 2):

One way to have this kind of behaviour is to use tmux to split the terminal
into 2 (or more) panes. Then run vim in one of them, and python (or whatever) in
another and use a plugin such as
[vim-slime](https://github.com/jpalardy/vim-slime) to send code from vim to the
other tmux pane:

[image]

Comment: Thought of tmux, but wasn't aware of vim-slime. Thanks. Will check it out!